# Extract numbers from multiple strings in an array and then sum - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array as seen in this screenshot:
[image]
It is dynamically created from stacks of data above them in the column.
What I would like to do is work with the numbers you see totaled in these cells *without* using helper cells. Is that possible?

For example, I would like to find the average number of lines, or I would like to find the average weight or volume (cft=cubic feet).

I can figure out a way to do this using helper cells, easily enough, but can I use one formula to parse the data and then compile it all in one single cell?

If the answer is "no", I will accept that as a viable response and mark it as such if nothing else is forthcoming.

Comment: It is questions like this with such varied answers that show the power of this community and excel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array formula like this and drag it down.

Use Evaluate formula option to see how it works in steps , alternatively you can select the part of the formula and press F9 to see the result of the selected part.

> =AVERAGE(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(B31:K31,SEARCH(" ",B31:K31)-1)),B31:K31))

[image]

Comment: That's excellent. I think the end result will end up being a dynamically sized named range (as the data expands to the right) using the offset function.
I'll mark this answer as correct, because I really do appreciate the community input, and between you and @Solar Mike I've learned a lot tonight.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the lines, assuming you have the text "lines" with the number, you could use:

```
=left(A1,find(" ",A1,1)-1)
```

for each cell and then calculate from there... Assumed the data starts in cell A1...

Sometimes the4 result is not recognized as a number so:

```
=left(A1,find(" ",A1,1)-1)*1
```

can change that..

Comment: Seriously awesome. So here's my modified formula that works... I had no idea we could do this!! This is exciting:
`=SUM(LEFT(B31:L31,FIND(" ",B31:L31,1)-1)*1)` (this is a scaled down version of what I'll be doing, but for the example given, this is what works).
Once I've entered in that formula, I've entered it as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter
If you wouldn't mind updating the solution, I'll mark it correct.

THANK YOU!

Comment: I had no idea we could use an array inside of the `LEFT` and that's where I was stalling out.

Comment: Tell you what, post that answer yourself and I will vote it up because you took it further... Just glad it helped you. And then we have a simple case and a further example.

Answer (score 1):

Building off the response from @Solar Mike, I discovered I can embed an array inside of the `LEFT` function, and if you enter the formula as an array formula, you can make this work.

The solution that works for this: `=SUM(LEFT(B31:L31,FIND(" ",B31:L31,1)-1)*1)`

It needs to be entered as an array formula by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, this is what puts the "curly braces" around the formula, and you know you've done it correctly {}

Thank you @Solar Mike, I learned something new today!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of building a text string as the answer in the cells and then having to use complicated array formulas to remove the added text, you apply custom formatting,

for example #,##0 "lines"

Then you can just use standard AVERAGE etc formulas.

Comment: Dude... That just blew my mind all over again! That comment alone will save me hours of work with the spreadsheets I'm building for work. Being able to keep my data numerical to work with however I want... Damn... I have so many spreadsheets I need to go back and change!! Edit: THANK YOU.